# PHP-Prettyphoto plugin shows image as character

Tags: php, prettyphoto

i am using prettyphoto in my website,and i keep my photo names on mysql database,and show them in foreach loop.when website loaded they look fine but when i click photos instead of showing photos it gives some characters like

����JFIFHH���ExifMM*bj(1r2��i�� ��' ��'Adobe Photoshop CS4 Windows2014:06:30 15:25:13�����&(.[HH����JFIFHH��Adobe_CM��Adobed����          ����"�� ��?   3!1AQa"q�2���B#$R�b34r��C%�S���cs5���&D�TdE(its very long text but i just cut here)

PHP code that i use in foreach loop to show images

```
echo "<div class=\"port-item showme\" data-cat=\"photography\">";
    echo "<div class=\"port-overlay\">";
    echo "<img src=\"panel/proje/".$row['path']."\" alt=\"Portfolio Image\">";
    echo "<a class=\"project-btn\" href=\"panel/proje/".$row['path']."\"><i class=\"fa fa-search\"></i></a>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess is that your web server does not send the proper header for the content-type.
Your browser end up showing the binary soup instead of interpreting it.

Comment: first i thought same but not worked.there was a problem about some class and its fixed now.thx for the answer anyway